# Footer not on the bottom of page, but on the bottom of background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, footer

I want to place a footer on the bottom of my web, but it is sticky to the bottom of background image. I was trying a lot of tricks, but I cannot place it under all content on the bottom of the website (I don't want to make it as fixed, but I want to make it visible below all content, once web is scrolled down totally).[image: please see attached image with desirable position of the footer]

Please find below the code I am using:

**HTML** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="background">
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <h1>xxxxxx<h1>
            <h2>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx<h2>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer">Footer text</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS** :

```
    body, html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.background { 
    background-image: url("xxx.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.text {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70%;
}

.footer {
   position: absolute;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}
```

I have checked all answers in another topics, but still cannot find solution of my problem. Thank you for your assistance.

Greetings,
Mat

Answer (score 0):

Change the css class footer as this to remove sticky footer:

```
.footer {
   position: relative;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` from your `.footer` class.

```
.footer {
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
   display: block;
}
```